# Deadly Defense/Critical Hit

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

When calculating damage on a successful critical hit, do you double the damage die from the feat Deadly Defense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Extra damage *dice* are typically applied separately on a critical hit

The *Rules Compendium* on Multiplying Damage says

> Sometimes damage is multiplied, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage dice and add all modifiers multiple times. Total the results. **Extra damage dice** over and above a weapon’s normal damage, such as those dealt by precision damage abilities…, **are never multiplied.** (17)

Emphasis mine. This includes the "extra 1d6 points of damage with any light weapon or with any weapon to which the Weapon Finesse feat applies" that's gained from the feat Deadly Defense (*Complete Scoundrel* 76).